# Chrome window pops up when saving .py files AFTER installing webdriver-manager

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, webdriver-manager

I am facing a curious problem, that chrome will start and shows for a couple of seconds before closing when i use VS Code and save a .py file. This happens over and over again. I first thought this is caused by an VSC extension or maybe Black formatter, but it is caused by webdriver-manager.

I can delete webdriver_manager and webdriver_manager-3.8.5.dist-info in .venv and the popup doesn't show up. Once i use python -m pip install --upgrade webdriver-manager again it comes back.

The exe path of Chrome, that is loaded, is C:\Users<MY USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application.

Any clues how to solve this annoying problem?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalled vscode?

Comment: Did you install some extensions, and the shortcut key to open the browser conflicts with the command to save the file?

Comment: Well this was my only option and i found that i have set "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true, in my workspace's settings json. Setting this to false remove the popup. Any clue why?

Comment: By "code" you mean the code in my .py file? It didn´t need any. Saving an empty file already caused the popup. Thx anyway for the input! :)